# Not getting Addview option when right click on ActionResult method in mvc controller using visual studio 2015 Asp.net 5

Tags: asp.net-core

I shocked when i right click on Action result method, I am unable to see Addview option/ goto view option. How to add view to action by right click on action method in visual studio 2015 Asp.net 5. Can any one tell me solution?